# Custom UIButton, -(IBAction)action:(id)sender fail

Tags: ios, uibutton

I created a custom UIButton with this code.

```
@implementation SessionButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withSessionObject:(SessionObject*)obj
     {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
        self.sessionObj = obj;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And allocated with this...

```
SessionButton *button = [[SessionButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, (startHour - 7)*80 + startMinute + 2, 220, height -4) withSessionObject:obj];
```

When I try to check it with an NSLog, it's perfect. I initialised the button with my object.

Now I have to give it a action. So I wrote this.

```
[button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(viewForSessions:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here is the viewForSessions method:

```
- (IBAction) viewForSessions:(id)sender {
    SessionButton *mBut = (SessionButton*) sender;
    SessionObject *obj = mBut.sessionObj;
    NSString *title = nil;
    switch (obj.type) {
        case 2:
            title = @"Konferans";
            break;
        case 3:
            title = @"Panel";
            break;
        case 4:
            title = @"İnteraktif";
            break;
        case 5:
            title = @"Forum";
            break;
    } //and it goes on....... a bit long
```

My problem is, after calling the selector, the **id** named sender **A** button, I checked with an NSLog. But it is not my button. It doesn't have any initialised SessionObject, it returns nil. Am I doing something wrong? Some help would be great.

Comment: OMG.. I cleaned the project and it works now :/

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code:

```
- (IBAction) viewForSessions:(SessionButton *)sender 
{
    SessionObject *obj = sender.sessionObj;
    NSString *title = nil;
    switch (obj.type) {
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: property sessionObj not found on object of type boa boa boa it says.

Comment: change method declaration - (IBAction) viewForSessions:(SessionButton *)sender

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar - you can accept my answer if it's helpful for you :)

Comment: It is helpful. But was not a solution.. sender is a id, and id has not a property named sessionObj.. it gives compile error. =)

Comment: Look at my method there is.. sender is SessionButton not id

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar id is a pointer to an instance of a class. You can send any message to it, and won't get any compile error.

Comment: @lancy   yeah I know.. But it gives.. Don't know why.